# middleware not working on connect HTTP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

I am reading Professional Node.js and i'm trying to understand connect HTTP middleware framework. I created a simple middleware that returns a function that replies with a custom test string:

```
function replyText(text) {
  return function(req, res) {
    res.end(text);
  };
}

module.exports = replyText;
```

But when i try to use this middleware in a connect server. Node gives me an error:

```
/Users/socomo22/work/hello_world_app_v2.js:8
var app = connect.createServer(replyText('Hello World!'));
                  ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

But when i simply use:

```
var app = connect();
app.listen(8080)
```

It runs without giving any error. I don't understand whether i'm doing any syntatical mistake. How would i use this simple middleware? This is my connect server file:

```
var connect = require('connect');

// middlewares
var replyText = require('./reply_text');

var app = connect();

var app = connect.createServer(replyText('Hello World!'));
app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('listening on 8080 port')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by [documentation](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/#user-content-mount-middleware) use `use` API to mount a middleware and a `http` module to create an instance of server although you can create an instance just with connect as pointed [here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/#user-content-create-a-server-from-the-app).

As pointed by @FranciscoPresencia adding `.js` extension while you require a your local module is optional.

```
var replyText = require('./reply_text.js');
```

**So your code should look like this and i tested it. Working as intended**

```
var connect = require('connect')
var http = require('http')
var app = connect();

// middlewares
var replyText = require('./reply_text.js');
app.use(replyText('Hello World!'));

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('listening on 8080 port')
});
```

**Note:** Try to avoid ports like *8080, 80* etc as its a reserved ports that might be used by other apps. This sometimes may cause node to fail.

---

**Adding the output screenshot for your reference**

[image]

Comment: `.js` is not really required in `require()` if he uses the `./` as he's doing. +1 for the `.use()`

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia but the code will be legible if added the extension. So i emphasised on good practice.

Comment: Well that's highly subjective, and definitely not a good practice or conventiom in Node.js so far. Furthermore, the language used in the answer makes it seem like it's required.

Answer (score 0):

Here You can start server in this way...

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');
var app = connect();
var replyIN = require('./connetFile.js')
app.use(replyIN('Hello there m back again'));
http.createServer(app).listen(8888,function(){console.log('Server has started');});
```

And this is your connectFile.js

```
function replyIN(text){                                                                                              
    return function (req, res) {                                                                                      
        res.end(text);                                                                                                 
    };                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                   
module.exports = replyIN;
```